# C++ NetBEAN cout Error?

Tags: c++, netbeans, cout

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

    cout << "COME AT ME BRO!\n"
    return 0;
}
```

It says cout is unable to resolve identifier

The C++ code assistance is setup properly, I'm just not sure whatelse it could possibly be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not include `<iostream>` and thus the identifier `std::cout` is never declared or defined in your program.

Comment: Great, now I'm having the issue of running it. Gives the directory of my project and says "error while loading shared libraries. Cannot open shared objects file: No such file or directory.

Comment: @Eric C: Open another question. If my answer solved this specific problem, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You're including the wrong header file. It should be :

```
#include <iostream>
```